# Occasionally I see camera usage indicator as I unlock my iPhone

Tags: iphone, security

I see the green dot on screen as I am about to unlock my iPhone, what can cause this? This does not happen every time, but it happens occasionally! I am on iPhone 12 Pro running 14.7.1.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have found that it happens because when pulling the screen is swept to the right which triggers the camera shortcut on lock screen. I confirmed it by looking at the control center showing which app used the camera recently.